How to daisychain with ferrules into screw-down connections?
I am installing some architrave power sockets into a garage ceiling, so I have flexibility to move light fixtures around.
Country is New Zealand, and the line voltage specs are 230V AC 50 HZ.
I have run 1.5mm2 cable, but there are points where I want one socket to have two wires, an incoming and an outgoing.
I have been using the correct size ferrule, but now I want to put two wires under one screw.
Do I put two wires into one larger ferrule?

OR Do I put two ferrules under one screw?

Wire nuts are not an option here - I could pigtail out to a three-way joiner, but that needs its own junction box.
What's the best way to do this?   Extension question, what if there were more-than-two wires coming to the same point?

The two photos are mockups - please disregard that the ferrules are not crimped, and are the wrong colour/size, and are not under the screw.  Its just for illustration purposes.

Just a note, but there are ferrules specifically designed to put two wires in (the insulated portion is more rectangular to fit the wires side-by-side).


I am installing some architrave power sockets into a garage ceiling, so I have flexibility to move light fixtures around.

Batten sockets are more usual in that application.
SFAIK ferrules are not required (although this may have changed since I last looked), If you are going to use them put all the wires into a single ferrule.
1.5mm2 seems kind of skinny for outlets.
(but this is a lighting circuit, not a GPO circuit, so assuming 10A breaker or smaller this is fine)
You are absolutely allowed to use those holes to join multiple wires, this is why they are 5mm diameter.

They're dedicated lighting outlets on the ceiling, only for LED shop lights not general usage.  Each outlet is labelled "lighting only" so complies.

I ended up using the ferrules with figure-8 style entrances, and twisting the two sets of wire totether before crimping and trimming the ends.  It made the job take longer but was easier because a lot of ferrule addition could be done either on the ground, or above the ceiling rather than immediately below the ceiling.

Batten holders would not work - I wanted short LED tubes not conventional light bulbs.

batten sockets, an outlet that takes a regular appliance plug and screws (or nails) directly to a solid surface

Ahhh a surface-mount socket then?  Excellent idea, would be perfect if the trusses were exposed, but this garage has a ceiling and I wanted the wiring to go above that.
